# TYPO3: pop-up on every page

Tags: javascript, typo3, typoscript

I would like to add a pop-up with a custom message that appears on every page.

I use bootstrap so I could use a modal ?
What's the easiest option ? I couldn't find an extension for it

Answer (score 0):

Therefore you don't need an extension but a HTML markup (realized in your (Fluid?-)templates) and some individual CSS and javascript.

Be sure your information is on every page as an ordinary content (you will find enough answers to this in the web) with an unique identification (e.g. div#modalId), then make sure that this content is changed visibly into a modal, either with pure CSS, or with javascript.